# Value error, when comparing two values in python! ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous

Tags: python, valueerror

I am trying two compare two values, which have type

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> this is for study1

<class 'PyPDF2.generic.TextStringObject'> this is for mob.iloc[16][1]

This is my code

```
if mob.iloc[16][1] != study1 :
                print('Buisness Unit Value is incorrect')
```

I am getting an error : ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You are trying to compare a one single value `mob.iloc[16][1]` with a complete column of the DataFrame, that's why you are getting the error. What is `study1` here?

Comment: query1=  "select BusinessUnit from [TestTable].[dbo].[ProjectDetails](nolock) where ProjectName = 'Test'; "
study1 = pd.read_sql(query1, cnxn)..

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
Traceback:
File "c:\users\heba.fatima\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 350, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\heba.fatima\Desktop\Hiba Temp folder\final-fire\saad files\Streamlit\app_test.py", line 865, in <module>
    if mob.iloc[16][1] != study1 :
File "c:\users\heba.fatima\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1442, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(

Comment: This is the error you get when you compare a single value with an array. Try to resolve that...it hard to find where you going wrong with a reproducible code snippet.